# Plotting a infinite potential well (double well)

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-8

I've been trying to plot a double well potential graph with a piecewise potential function that has 3 regions, my code however is not properly plotting what I am looking for.

This is what I got so far:

[image]

As you can see the plot start in the middle of the barrier between the two potential wells. It should start before the barrier at `vL` but is not. Any help will do, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Scrape-n-paste into an empty fresh notebook and evaluate

```
L = 1;
bWidth = L/5;
v0 = 50;
vL = 4;
vD = 6;
v[x_] := 1 /; x < 0;
v[x_] := 1 /; x > L;
v[x_] := v0 /; (L - bWidth)/2 < x < (L + bWidth)/2;
v[x_] := vL /; 0 < x < (L - bWidth)/2;
v[x_] := vD /; (L + bWidth)/2 < x < L;
Plot[v[x], {x, -.25, 1.25}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]